# How to export angular components into PDF?

Tags: angular5, jspdf

I am working on html to PDF export. I have multiple components in my page which I need to export to PDF.

In first component I have html table from below code

```
<div id="contentToConvert">
    <h3>Top Ten</h3>

    <p *ngIf="!this.dataAvailable">No data available for now. Please use the filter panel.</p>

    <ng-container *ngIf="this.dataAvailable">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let key of newData">
            <app-table [data]="this.data[key]"></app-table>
        </ng-container>

    </ng-container>
</div>
```

In another component, I have button

```
<!-- PDF EXPORT  -->
<div class="col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-9 col-sm-3 ta-r mt-4">
    <button type="button" (click)="downloadPDF()" class="uni-button def">Export to PDF</button>
</div>
```

I am using following code to export to PDF.

```
downloadPDF() {
    let data = document.getElementById("contentToConvert");
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
        const imgWidth = 180;
        const imgHeight = 160;

        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        const position = 40;
        doc.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 15, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        doc.save('testFile.pdf');

    })
```

Using above code, I can generate PDF for the content inside contentToConvert component only. But I have multiple component in my page. Lets say I have contentToConvert1, contentToConvert2, contentToConvert3 as well.

How can I export all these to single pdf file?